# How do I prevent superfluous quotation marks in my restify response body?

Tags: node.js, restify

I have created a simple `restify` server, and I am attempting to return a string in my response body:

```
server.post('/authurl', function authurl(req, res, next) {
    res.send(dhs.getAuthorizeUrl());
    return next();
});
```

However, I'm noticing that the response body is surrounded by double quotation marks that I didn't ask for:

```
"https://some.url.com/oauth/v4/authorize?client_id=someid&scope=SOMESCOPE"
```

I've verified that these extra quotation marks are *not* coming from the `getAuthorizeUrl` method - it returns the bare URL.

How can I get rid of these unwanted quotation marks?

Comment: It seems like the response value is automatically converted to JSON.

Answer (score 4):

After a little experimentation, I found I could eliminate the quotation marks by explicitly specifying the Content-Type of my response:

```
server.post('/authurl', function authurl(req, res, next) {
    /*jslint unparam: true*/
    res.contentType = "text/plain"; // needed so the platform doesn't add superfluous quotation marks around the URL in the response body
    res.send(dhs.getAuthorizeUrl());
    return next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [**documentation**](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#content-negotiation), if you don't want to magically convert the response to JSON, you can do

```
var body = 'hello world';
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});
res.write(body);
res.end();
```